# Python comparing variables in 2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare the values of 2 data frame. If any of the values is different, I will return that row.

```
df1
     Value1 Value2
Name     
a      1      1
b      1      2
c      0      1

df2
     Value Value2
Name     
a      1      1
b      1      1
c      1      1
```

I did a df1==df2

```
df3
     Value Value2
Name
a    True  True 
b    True  False
c    False True
```

I want to return only b and c, how can I do it?
I do not want to do

```
df3[(df3['Value']==False)|(df3['Value2'==False)]
```

because I may have more than 2 columns and columns names can differ

Comment: Do you want to do something like this: `df1[df1!=df2].dropna(how='all')`

Comment: Yes this works! @acushner has a similar one below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should do it:

```
df3[~df3.all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a data file (d3.txt) or list of data like (line),

```
line = [i.strip().split() for i in open("d3.txt").readlines()]

print line 
[['#df3'], ['#', 'Value', 'Value2'], ['#Name'], ['#a', 'True', 'True'], ['#b', 'True', 'False'], ['#c', 'False', 'True']]

 for i in line[:][:]:
    mydict[i[0]] = ",".join(li[li.index(i)][1:])
```

I just created a dictionary. So you can call

```
print mydict
print mydict['#a'] #Depend of which name you want to look.
```

The output is

```
{'#': 'Value,Value2', '#c': 'False,True', '#b': 'True,False', '#a': 'True,True', '#Name': '', '#df3': ''}
True,True
```

Or you can do this way without creating the dictionary,

```
for n in range(len(line)):
    if (line[n][0] == '#c' or line[n][0]== '#b'):
        print line[n][:]
```

And the output is (maybe this is what you want):

```
['#b', 'True', 'False']  
['#c', 'False', 'True']
```